# Chain records in DataFrame by using a recursive function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I have following DataFrame:

```
+----------+------------+-------------------+--------+----------+
|IDENTIFIER|NEXT_RECORDS|TYPE               |POSITION|FRUIT     |
+----------+------------+-------------------+--------+----------+
|1_1       |[3_1]       |Ready for next     |E       |Apple     |
|2_1       |[3_1]       |Ready for next     |E       |Apple     |
|3_1       |[4_1]       |Ready from previous|X       |Lemon     |
|3_1       |[5_1]       |Ready from previous|X       |Lemon     |
|4_1       |[6_1]       |Ready for next     |X       |Orange    |
|5_1       |[7_1]       |Ready for next     |X       |Orange    |
|6_1       |[8_1]       |Ready from previous|X       |Strawberry|
|7_1       |[8_1]       |Ready from previous|X       |Strawberry|
|8_1       |[]          |Ready for next     |X       |Pineapple |
|9_1       |[10_1]      |Ready for next     |E       |Cherry    |
|10_1      |[]          |Ready from previous|X       |Orange    |
+----------+------------+-------------------+--------+----------+
```

This table represents some movements linked to each other based on the "NEXT_RECORDS" column. I would like to add an additional column which tells me what the first "FRUIT" was from my entire chain. I know that all movements with TYPE = "Ready for next" **AND**  POSITION = "E" is the start of a chain. So basically I try to achieve something like:

```
+----------+------------+-------------------+--------+----------+-----------+
|IDENTIFIER|NEXT_RECORDS|TYPE               |POSITION|FRUIT     |FIRST_FRUIT|
+----------+------------+-------------------+--------+----------+-----------+
|1_1       |[3_1]       |Ready for next     |E       |Apple     |Apple      |
|2_1       |[3_1]       |Ready for next     |E       |Apple     |Apple      |
|3_1       |[4_1]       |Ready from previous|X       |Lemon     |Apple      |
|3_1       |[5_1]       |Ready from previous|X       |Lemon     |Apple      |
|4_1       |[6_1]       |Ready for next     |X       |Orange    |Apple      |
|5_1       |[7_1]       |Ready for next     |X       |Orange    |Apple      |
|6_1       |[8_1]       |Ready from previous|X       |Strawberry|Apple      |
|7_1       |[8_1]       |Ready from previous|X       |Strawberry|Apple      |
|8_1       |[]          |Ready for next     |X       |Pineapple |Apple      |
|9_1       |[10_1]      |Ready for next     |E       |Cherry    |Cherry     |
|10_1      |[]          |Ready from previous|X       |Orange    |Cherry     |
+----------+------------+-------------------+--------+----------+-----------+
```

In this example movements 1_1 and 2_1 are the beginning of a chain, and 9_1 is the beginning of a chain. So the first fruit for the first movement is Apple and the first fruit of the second movement is Cherry.

Now I've already tried something, but it's a little complex:

First I split my input based on type:

```
val readyForNext = input.filter(col("TYPE") === "Ready for next")
val readyFromPrevious = input.filter(col("TYPE") === "Ready from previous")
```

I get the the movements at the start of the chain:

```
val firstRecords = readyForNext.filter(col("POSITION") === "E")
      .withColumn("FIRST_FRUIT", col("FRUIT"))
```

This will be my starting DataFrame. I've created a recursive function that starts with this DataFrame and joins the next movements and add the first fruit to those records:

```
var newCount = 0L
var counter = 0
var matchesFound = true
val columns = input.columns

def getMultipleLinks(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
   val oldResultCount = newCount

   val intermediate = if (counter % 2 == 0) {
     link(df, readyFromPrevious, columns)
   } else {
     link(df, readyForNext, columns)
   }

   counter += 1

   newCount = intermediate.filter(col("FIRST_FRUIT").isNull).count
   matchesFound = oldResultCount != newCount

   if (matchesFound) {
      val matches = getMultipleLinks(intermediate)
      matches
   } else {
      intermediate
   }
}

def link(from: DataFrame, to: DataFrame, columns: Array[String]): DataFrame = {
   val fromWithJoinKey = from.withColumn("JOIN_KEY", explode(col("NEXT_RECORDS")))
   val toWithJoinKey = to.withColumn("JOIN_KEY", col("IDENTIFIER"))

   fromWithJoinKey
     .as("left")
     .join(toWithJoinKey.as("right"), Seq("JOIN_KEY"), "right")
     .select("right.*", "left.FIRST_FRUIT")
     .distinct
     .withColumn("FIRST_FRUIT", when(col("FIRST_FRUIT").isNull, first("FIRST_FRUIT", ignoreNulls = true).over(Window.partitionBy("NEXT_RECORDS"))).otherwise(col("FIRST_FRUIT")))
     .drop("JOIN_KEY")
     .union(fromWithJoinKey.drop("JOIN_KEY"))
     .groupBy(columns.map(col): _*)
     .agg(
        first("FIRST_FRUIT", ignoreNulls = true).as("FIRST_FRUIT")
         )
    }

    getMultipleLinks(firstRecords).show(20, false)
```

This gives me the correct result, but is very inefficient ! When running this on a large dataset it will take Spark hours and finally result in a Java Heap Space error.

So my question is how can improve my current code or is there some other way to chain the movements without using the recursive function? 
And if there is no other way, will caching the intermediate DataFrame inside my recursive function help?

Comment: Hive you tried window functions ?

Comment: Yes I have but maybe not in a good way. How would you suggest I use them?

Comment: Doesn't look like a map-reduce problem. So I would suggest either to rethink data or rethink solution.

Comment: When saying rethink solution, do you mean not using Spark at all?

Comment: If you are on spark 2.4+ then you can use barrier execution mode. With MPI it should be way faster. Mapreduce is terribly iterative/recursive for this problem and in turn slow.

Comment: to complex for me, i didn't understood input data itself.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Make sure your IDENTIFIER is sort-able.

First, I created a new column FF_INTER based on the condition TYPE is Ready for next && POSITION is E which will have Fruit, else null.
Then use window to find the last not-null using `last` function, when ordered by IDENTIFIER

```
scala> df.show(false)
+----------+------------+-------------------+--------+----------+
|IDENTIFIER|NEXT_RECORDS|TYPE               |POSITION|FRUIT     |
+----------+------------+-------------------+--------+----------+
|11        |[31]        |Ready for next     |E       |Apple     |
|21        |[31]        |Ready for next     |E       |Apple     |
|31        |[41]        |Ready from previous|X       |Lemon     |
|31        |[51]        |Ready from previous|X       |Lemon     |
|41        |[61]        |Ready for next     |X       |Orange    |
|51        |[71]        |Ready for next     |X       |Orange    |
|61        |[81]        |Ready from previous|X       |Strawberry|
|71        |[81]        |Ready from previous|X       |Strawberry|
|81        |[]          |Ready for next     |X       |Pineapple |
|91        |[101]       |Ready for next     |E       |Cherry    |
|101       |[]          |Ready from previous|X       |Orange    |
+----------+------------+-------------------+--------+----------+


scala> 

scala> val dfFirstFruit = df.withColumn("FF_INTER", 
     |   when($"TYPE" === "Ready for next" && $"POSITION" === "E", $"FRUIT"))
dfFirstFruit: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [IDENTIFIER: int, NEXT_RECORDS: array<int> ... 4 more fields]

scala> 

scala> dfFirstFruit.show(false)
+----------+------------+-------------------+--------+----------+--------+
|IDENTIFIER|NEXT_RECORDS|TYPE               |POSITION|FRUIT     |FF_INTER|
+----------+------------+-------------------+--------+----------+--------+
|11        |[31]        |Ready for next     |E       |Apple     |Apple   |
|21        |[31]        |Ready for next     |E       |Apple     |Apple   |
|31        |[41]        |Ready from previous|X       |Lemon     |null    |
|31        |[51]        |Ready from previous|X       |Lemon     |null    |
|41        |[61]        |Ready for next     |X       |Orange    |null    |
|51        |[71]        |Ready for next     |X       |Orange    |null    |
|61        |[81]        |Ready from previous|X       |Strawberry|null    |
|71        |[81]        |Ready from previous|X       |Strawberry|null    |
|81        |[]          |Ready for next     |X       |Pineapple |null    |
|91        |[101]       |Ready for next     |E       |Cherry    |Cherry  |
|101       |[]          |Ready from previous|X       |Orange    |null    |
+----------+------------+-------------------+--------+----------+--------+


scala> 

scala> val overColumns = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window.orderBy("IDENTIFIER")
overColumns: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec@6b31241e

scala> dfFirstFruit.withColumn("FRUIT_FIRST", 
     |   org.apache.spark.sql.functions.last("FF_INTER", true).over(overColumns))
res11: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [IDENTIFIER: int, NEXT_RECORDS: array<int> ... 5 more fields]

scala> res11.show(false)
20/04/29 12:28:26 WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
+----------+------------+-------------------+--------+----------+--------+-----------+
|IDENTIFIER|NEXT_RECORDS|TYPE               |POSITION|FRUIT     |FF_INTER|FRUIT_FIRST|
+----------+------------+-------------------+--------+----------+--------+-----------+
|11        |[31]        |Ready for next     |E       |Apple     |Apple   |Apple      |
|21        |[31]        |Ready for next     |E       |Apple     |Apple   |Apple      |
|31        |[41]        |Ready from previous|X       |Lemon     |null    |Apple      |
|31        |[51]        |Ready from previous|X       |Lemon     |null    |Apple      |
|41        |[61]        |Ready for next     |X       |Orange    |null    |Apple      |
|51        |[71]        |Ready for next     |X       |Orange    |null    |Apple      |
|61        |[81]        |Ready from previous|X       |Strawberry|null    |Apple      |
|71        |[81]        |Ready from previous|X       |Strawberry|null    |Apple      |
|81        |[]          |Ready for next     |X       |Pineapple |null    |Apple      |
|91        |[101]       |Ready for next     |E       |Cherry    |Cherry  |Cherry     |
|101       |[]          |Ready from previous|X       |Orange    |null    |Cherry     |
+----------+------------+-------------------+--------+----------+--------+-----------+
```

Comment: Maybe my example isn't that good but it's also possible that the identifiers are not chronologically. So for example identifier 11 could have 101 as next record (Cherry). And 21 could  have 31 as next record (Apple). Two different movements in that case.

Comment: as longs as identifiers are sortable, they don't need to be in order. Because val overColumns = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window.```orderBy```("IDENTIFIER")  will take care of sorting/ordering. You use the column(s) that you think will give some order to your data.